# Jira API: How to search a nested field?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use the Jira API to query some data. It is working fine with below API request:

```
GET https://jira/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=-1&fields=summary,worklog
```

I get the below result:

```json
"issues":  [
               {
                   "expand":  "",
                   "id":  "12345",
                   "self":  "url",
                   "key":  "ABC-1234",
                   "fields":  {
                                  "summary": "some summary",
                                  "worklog": {
                                        "startAt":0,
                                        "maxResults":20,
                                        "total":30
                                        "worklog":[]
                                  }
                            }
                }
        ]
```

I tried to update my initial API request with `fields=summary,worklog,worklog.maxResults=-1` but couldn't get it to work
I need the `maxResults` to be increased so I get all the worklog.